# Host Sinatra Web Site in Team City

Tags: sinatra, apache2.4, teamcity-9.0

Whenever I open my `team city` triggered runs to looks at the results, I want to provide a tab where I can see my `Ruby-Sinatra` web server.

Ideally that should result in a `Same Domain` Error because `team city` tabs are i-frames, If I give a html page with a hyper link to the web server.

How can I go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Same Domain Issue, I set the `X-Frame-Option` to *, This way it worked in IE and Firefox as it explicitly understood the option. However in Chrome it did not understand the * option so bypassed it all together, which did the trick.